# heap corruption when changing index order c++

Tags: c++

```
double*** RGB = new double**[4];
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        RGB[i] = new double*[6];
        for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++)
        {
            RGB[i][j] = new double[4];
        }   
    }

std::vector<int> columnIndex(24);
std::vector<int> rowIndex(24);
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
    {
        columnIndex[i*4 + j] = i;
        rowIndex[i*4+ j] = j;
    }           
}

for (int n = 0; n < 24; n++)
{
  for (int ch = 0; ch < 3; ch++)
  {
     .... 
     /*RGB[rowIndex[n]][columnIndex[n]][ch] = median;*/ //old line working
        RGB[ch][rowIndex[n]][columnIndex[n]] = median;  //new line causing the heap corruption ... I think
  }
}

for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{       
    for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++)
    {
        delete[] RGB[i][j]; // crash is here when i and j are 0
    }   
    delete[] RGB[i];
}
delete [] RGB;
```

my old code before the change was working fine.
How ever I noticed I have a problem with the indexing so I had to make a fix.
after the fix I have a crash - i am using Xunit. it says:

```
The thread 'Win64 Thread' (0x1f1c) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
HEAP[xunit.console.clr4.exe]: Heap block at 000000001D3C4820 modified at 000000001D3C4884 past requested size of 54
Windows has triggered a breakpoint in xunit.console.clr4.exe.

This may be due to a corruption of the heap, which indicates a bug in xunit.console.clr4.exe or any of the DLLs it has loaded.

This may also be due to the user pressing F12 while xunit.console.clr4.exe has focus.
```

Comment: Did you check the content of `rowIndex`?  Is `rowIndex` itself big enough to hold 24 values?
There is no guarantee `new` allocates the memory contiguously.

Comment: This is one big poster question for why you should avoid raw arrays... especially with multiple levels of indirection....

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Comment: @Gilad Why didn't you just use `std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<double>>>` and avoid these issues?

Comment: `double***` will get you in trouble sooner or later. See if `std::map` suits you.

Comment: @Gilad I am not trying to insult you.  If I was to give you an answer that is what I would do.  Maybe you could do it to and find the answer yourself.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie performance of those things is terrible

Comment: Terrible? You base that claim on what, exactly? If you think the indirection of nested vectors is bad, you haven't profiled your own code yet.

Comment: nest vector or array - i.e std::array are easy to use, but when releasing the memory it is time consuming, I have tried that solution already thanks and it is working fine, however i tried to do it with pointers and until now it worked fine.

Comment: `std::array` doesn't allocate memory dynamically on it's own. If you are going to criticize something, don't do it out of ignorance.

Comment: @StoryTeller I tried it, I created an std:vector<std:vector<std::array<4,double>>> it was time consuming, i meant the release of the vectors took time.

Comment: RGB has dimensions 4x6x4. The assignment to `RGB[ch][rowIndex[n]][columnIndex[n]] = median` will segfault. You seem to have switched the order from the commented-out call.

Comment: @Gilad - *performance of those things is terrible* -- 1) Did you profile your code to determine this?  2) What good is performance if your "superior performing" code has bugs?  3) If you wanted performance, then why not  create a 3 dimensional array outright and skip all of the dynamic allocation (`double RGB[4][6][4];` or `std::array<std::array<std::array<double, 4>,6>,4> RGB;`)

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I will try not allocate it dynamically you are correct double RGB[4][6][4]. I tried to use pointers no special reason for not using nested std::array, just tried it in another version. I do not understand why is it so bad to try to use pointers.. do I really have to use STL ??

Comment: Vector of vector and dynamic array of dynamic array are equally slow in my experience. But no I don't have profile data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using my debugger I noticed when you store the values into `columnIndex` you use

```
columnIndex[i*4 + j] = i;
```

Which gives you

```
0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5
```

When you go to use it in

```
RGB[ch][rowIndex[n]][columnIndex[n]] = median;
```

`[columnIndex[n]]` will be `[0, 5]` but you only allocated 4 columns with

```
RGB[i][j] = new double[4];
```

which gives you valid indes of `[0, 3]` so you are going off the end of the array.

It looks like all you need to do is flip the `i` and `j` between the `columnIndex` and `rowIndex` setup

```
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
    {
        columnIndex[i * 4 + j] = j;
        rowIndex[i * 4 + j] = i;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's what I said above :)